# Getting error messages but can still run application

Tags: command-line, gtk, spotify

I installed Spotify thru snap and when I run it the application comes up but I get these error messages

```
Gtk-Message: 13:12:30.917: Failed to load module "gail"
Gtk-Message: 13:12:30.917: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"
Gtk-Message: 13:12:30.919: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
```

then my user@....~$ (don't know what to call this line) doesn't come back up until the the application is closed so I can't enter any more commands and have to close Spotify to continue using the terminal.

Spotify runs fine and I get no error messages when I run it using the GUI, error is only present when run thru the termial

Where can I download these modules and is there a way to get around not being able to use the terminal until the application is closed?

Thanks for the help

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize someone had responded, I'm running ubuntu 20.04.1

Answer (score 1):

The (3) modules can been installed as follows:

```
sudo apt install libgail-3-0 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libcanberra-gtk-module
```

The errors you're receiving are warnings; that's why Spotify still works. To run a program from the terminal and be able to use it, you need to add an **&** at the end of the command line; this will put the command in the background.

BTW, your question about what to call "user@....~$" - this is known as a shell prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue. I solved it by uing the GUI (go to the graphical user intereface - Software) and key in the search box "the program you intend to install (eg. for me it was the Falkon web browser so I keyed Falkon.

And the icon appeared and asked for password authentication and it ran to install and hit "Lauch" once the installation finishes, this "Launch" button would appear and everything works and my Falkon Icon appears in my desktop panel. Hope this helps.